# Normalizing a table in Tableau

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, normalization

I'd like to normalize a table in Tableau and have the normalization shift as I apply filters. Here is an example of a table I'd like to normalize:

| Store | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Mansfield | $1000 |
| Attleboro | $500 |
| Foxboro | $250 |
| Plainville | $125 |

What I want to do is normalize to 1 so the table will end up looking like this:

| Store | Sales | Normalized |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mansfield | $1000 | 1.0 |
| Attleboro | $500 | 0.50 |
| Foxboro | $250 | 0.25 |
| Plainville | $125 | 0.125 |

Additionally, I'd like these values to shift when I apply a new table.

For example:

| Candy | Store | Sales | Normalized |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Mansfield | $100 | 1.0 |
|  | Attleboro | $75 | 0.75 |
|  | Foxboro | $20 | 0.20 |
|  | Plainville | $6 | 0.06 |

Here's the calculated field I thought might work, but didn't:

```
([Sales] - { FIXED[Store]:MIN([Sales])})

/

(({FIXED[Store]:MAX([Sales])} - {FIXED[Store]:MIN([Sales])}))
```

I'm fairly confident I need a LOD fixed calculation, but I can't seem to find the right formula to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [Store] will remain in the view, you can use a simpler calc.

```
sum([Sales])/window_max(sum([Sales]))
```